# CMake can't find ROS package

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04, ros, point-cloud-library

## What I want to realize

I am planning to realize (http://ros-developer.com/2017/05/15/object-recognition-and-6dof-pose-estimation-with-pcl-pointcloud-and-ros/) However, the following error occurs during CMake: Please teach if there are people who can understand the solution.

## Error messages

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ecl_geometry" with
any of the following names:
ecl_geometryConfig.cmake
ecl_geometry-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "ecl_geometry" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"ecl_geometry_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"ecl_geometry" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)

Could not find the required component 'ecl_geometry'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ecl_geometry" with
any of the following names:

ecl_geometryConfig.cmake
ecl_geometry-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "ecl_geometry" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"ecl_geometry_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"ecl_geometry" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)

CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
```

## CMakeLists

```
project(tracker)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS “-std=c++0x ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}”)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ecl_geometry roscpp rospy tf image_transport cv_bridge moveit_ros_planning_interface moveit_msgs moveit_planners_ompl moveit_ros_move_group moveit_ros_planning dynamic_reconfigure)

find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED COMPONENTS

common
octree
io
kdtree
search
sample_consensus
filters
2d
features
registration
geometry
visualization
outofcore
surface
keypoints
ml
segmentation
recognition
people
tracking
stereo
)

MESSAGE(“PCL_FOUND:” ${PCL_FOUND})
MESSAGE(“PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS:” ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
MESSAGE(“PCL_LIBRARIES:” ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
MESSAGE(“PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS:” ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
MESSAGE(“PCL_VERSION:” ${PCL_VERSION})
MESSAGE(“PCL_COMPONENTS:” ${PCL_COMPONENTS})
MESSAGE(“PCL_DEFINITIONS:” ${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED )
add_definitions(${HDF5_DEFINITIONS})
include_directories(${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${HDF5_LIBRARIES})

include_directories( ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(tracking_object sample.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tracking_object ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_TRACKING_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_COMMON_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_IO_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_SEARCH_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_FILTERS_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_APPS_LIBRARIES})
```

## Implementation environment

Ubuntu 16.04LTS

CMake 3.11.2

ROS Kinetic

Comment: you may need to edit your post so it is more readable

Comment: @hellp_nezumi: Your code and error message are't only formatted bad, it is also difficult to format them properly: you have **lost** some **newlines** already. Please, insert original code into the question (with **newlines preserved**), and use `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button for format it. The do the same with the error message.

Comment: BTW, the error message clearly says, that CMake cannot find `ecl_geometryConfig`. Do you have this package installed on your computer?

Comment: @ user1506104: Sorry, I fixed the format

Comment: @Tsyvarev：ecl_geometry exists, but ecl_geometryConfig is missing.
Do I generate it?

Comment: I don't know. If this file doesn't come with your `ecl_geometry` , installation you cannot generate it. BTW, I suggest to follow the second CMake Error, and add `cmake_minimum_required` to the top of your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build system cannot find the ecl-geometry package. Probably because it is not installed.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ecl-geometry
```

This should fix your problem.